# Show audio waveform in FCP video?

Tags: audio

How can I show the audio waveform in a video similar to the one below?

I'm using Final Cut Pro X on OS X 10.10 Yosemite.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/9644/how-do-i-turn-audio-into-video-that-is-show-the-waveforms-in-a-video

Comment: That 'duplicate' doesn't answer my question, hence why I asked another one.